# TO_CHAR template patterns case sensitivity

Tags: postgresql, to-char

The following query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR("date2", 'dd') AS "TEMP"
FROM "TestV1"."Calcs" AS "t"
GROUP BY "TEMP"
```

Behaves exactly the same as this one

```
SELECT TO_CHAR("date2", 'DD') AS "TEMP"
FROM "TestV1"."Calcs" AS "t"
GROUP BY "TEMP"
```

(Notice the difference in letters case of the template pattern, **DD** and **dd**)

Although [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) doesn't mention anything about case-sensitivity for the template patterns, It even states that there is a difference between using the templates **DAY**, **Day** and **day** which implies a case-sensitive handling mechanism.

So why does **dd** and **DD** behave the same ? Or did I miss anything ?

Comment: if you want capital digits for day number, use 'DD' if you wont small digits, use 'dd'. the problem is nobody notice the difference. but the date mask is case sensitive - true

Comment: Also  interesting is that if use one upper and one lower case pattern `Dd` or `dD` , result is totally different (it becomes `day of the week` two times).

Comment: So can I assume that for patterns that produce only digits, the pattern is case-insensitive, while for patterns that produce letters, the pattern is case-sensitive ?